# Installed favicons -> Undefined Variables -> Site Crashed

Tags: php, wordpress

**Please read before judging**

I just made favicons and uploaded them on the site. When I included them in the header suddenly everything crashed. I deleted the *W3 Total Cache* plugin because I had a idea of that the plugin was caching. And then everything was gone.

I turned on WP_DEBUG and currently I am getting the following errors:

> Notice: Undefined variable: feature in
>   /customers/a/2/1/domain/httpd.www/wp-content/themes/name/functions.php
>   on line 42
>
> Notice: Undefined variable: arguments in
>   /customers/a/2/1/domain/httpd.www/wp-content/themes/theme/functions.php
>   on line 42
>
> Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by
>   (output started at
>   /customers/a/2/1/domain/httpd.www/wp-content/themes/theme/functions.php:42)
>   in /customers/a/2/1/domain/httpd.www/wp-includes/pluggable.php
>   on line 1196

See page [here](http://goo.gl/9IsTIl)

**I have tried the following:**

- Changed to another Wordpress theme
- Contacted the host, but they could not help me cause this problem was about wordpress
- Searched online for advises
- Deleted all the changes that were made in header.php with including favicons
- Deleted all favicons uploaded

What I find interesting is that the custom field plugin *Types* is gone from the plugin page. I find this interesting because I remember the plugins to be kinda tricky to interact with. So could it be any troubles with that?

I also see that after deleting the favicons they still appear on the website. However, I do not have any cache on at the moment.

But else I have no idea of what is going on.

Using Filezilla I see that the Type plugin is there. I try to get an overview if some files has been changed, but can't find anything interesting.

But as advises on the web says, there is something wrong with how I use `add_theme_support`, is this correct? Maybe I am totally wrong...

**Here is my functions.php**

```
<?php

//Isotope
function add_isotope() {
    wp_register_script( 'isotope', get_template_directory_uri().'/js/isotope.pkgd.min.js', array('jquery'),  true );
    wp_register_script( 'isotope-init', get_template_directory_uri().'/js/isotope.js', array('jquery', 'isotope'),  true );

    wp_enqueue_script('isotope-init');
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'add_isotope' );


//Remove "more" jumping
function remove_more_jump_link($link) { 
    $offset = strpos($link, '#more-');
    if ($offset) {
        $end = strpos($link, '"',$offset);
    }
    if ($end) {
        $link = substr_replace($link, '', $offset, $end-$offset);
    }
    return $link;
}

add_filter('the_content_more_link', 'remove_more_jump_link');

//Remove WordPress Admin bar
    add_filter('show_admin_bar', '__return_false');

if ( function_exists( 'add_theme_support' ) ) { 
    add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails' ); 
    add_theme_support( 'nav-menus' );
}

add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'mytheme_custom_thumbnail_size' );
function mytheme_custom_thumbnail_size(){
    add_image_size( 'frontpage_thumb', 350, 220, array( 'center', 'center' ) ); // Hard crop center
}

function custom_theme_setup() {
    add_theme_support( $feature, $arguments );
}
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'custom_theme_setup' );


add_action('wp_head', 'my_js_var_stylesheet_directory', 9);
function my_js_var_stylesheet_directory() {
    echo '<script type="text/javascript">';
    echo 'var stylesheetDir = "' . get_bloginfo('stylesheet_directory') . '"';
    echo '</script>';
}

function disable_wp_emojicons() {

  // all actions related to emojis
  remove_action( 'admin_print_styles', 'print_emoji_styles' );
  remove_action( 'wp_head', 'print_emoji_detection_script', 7 );
  remove_action( 'admin_print_scripts', 'print_emoji_detection_script' );
  remove_action( 'wp_print_styles', 'print_emoji_styles' );
  remove_filter( 'wp_mail', 'wp_staticize_emoji_for_email' );
  remove_filter( 'the_content_feed', 'wp_staticize_emoji' );
  remove_filter( 'comment_text_rss', 'wp_staticize_emoji' );

  // filter to remove TinyMCE emojis
  add_filter( 'tiny_mce_plugins', 'disable_emojicons_tinymce' );
}
add_action( 'init', 'disable_wp_emojicons' );

?>
```

Could you please help me?

**UPDATE**

I was interested if anything worked, so I went to a specific post and pages.

[Here is a specific article written with Types](http://goo.gl/V3YQWq). Turns out it's being resent to the front page.

[Here is the 404 page](http://goo.gl/cP86LZ). Wow. This site actually works.

[Here is a page](http://goo.gl/Mq4rxp). Kinda works. But one error is showing up as a title. Else the same errors as the index.

Header.php can be found [here](http://pastebin.com/WeqkCgn1)

I added the favicons here:

```
<head>
    <meta charset="<?php bloginfo( 'charset' ); ?>" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1"> 
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="57x57" href="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory'); ?>/img/apple-touch-icon-57x57.png">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="60x60" href="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory'); ?>/img/apple-touch-icon-60x60.png">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="72x72" href="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory'); ?>/img/apple-touch-icon-72x72.png">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="76x76" href="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory'); ?>/img/apple-touch-icon-76x76.png">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="114x114" href="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory'); ?>/img/apple-touch-icon-114x114.png">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="120x120" href="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory'); ?>/img/apple-touch-icon-120x120.png">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="144x144" href="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory'); ?>/img/apple-touch-icon-144x144.png">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="152x152" href="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory'); ?>/img/apple-touch-icon-152x152.png">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="180x180" href="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory'); ?>/img/apple-touch-icon-180x180.png">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory'); ?>/img/favicon-32x32.png" sizes="32x32">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory'); ?>/img/favicon-194x194.png" sizes="194x194">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory'); ?>/img/favicon-96x96.png" sizes="96x96">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory'); ?>/img/android-chrome-192x192.png" sizes="192x192">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory'); ?>/img/favicon-16x16.png" sizes="16x16">
    <link rel="manifest" href="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory'); ?>/img/manifest.json">
    <meta name="msapplication-TileColor" content="#ffffff">
    <meta name="msapplication-TileImage" content="/mstile-144x144.png">
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#ffffff">
    <title><?php wp_title( '|', true, 'right' ); ?></title>
```

Latest header.php can be found here: http://pastebin.com/DCtJ6fMH

Comment: twice you post a message with **Please read before judging**... if your question is clear, we will always read it, and it looks like you describe well your questions, so no worries...

Comment: Sorry, I am scared of getting judged of the titles I set for some of my questions. I feel they are loose ends and does not provide enough detail. Anyways, I will update the question in a bit.

Comment: your title made me laugh personnaly, since we see the behavior with only few words, it's a good point to read it :)

Comment: To come back to the subject : you say you just uploaded the image, and added a line to include it... where did you include the favicon and how ?

Comment: About the cache, you say you have no cache, did you empty the navigator cache ? (using CTRL+F5)

Comment: I included the favicons in the header as normally. But by visiting websites online I saw that it needed to be a little more complicated than just one favicon. So I basically used codes provided by http://realfavicongenerator.net/. About the cache I first use private mode in Chrome if I believe that there are some cache going on...

Comment: I did it for my wordpress website, and I just had to add a line in the header, and upload the file in the root...

Comment: Can you show us your header codes please? You may use http://www.pastebin.com too. This "headers already sent" happens a lot, please check the "How do I solve the Headers already sent warning problem?" part of WP Codex faq https://codex.wordpress.org/FAQ_Troubleshooting.

Comment: Yes, I have been using that too. But for iphone and so on I wanted to make favicon for all plattforms. I will upload the whole header.php in pastebin right now. (Without Favicons, since the problem is still there)

Comment: Okay, but I think you should include the favicon codes too. So that we can see if there was an error.

Comment: Where in this header.php you added your favicons?

Comment: Sorry for not commenting. I will update the question right now.

Comment: Can you try adding those links below where you have other `<link>`elements? For example, below `<!-- Normalize CSS ---><link rel="https://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/3.0.2/normalize.css">`. Plus you should put back the deleted function codes.

Comment: I have readded the favicons, and favicons works, but something is still wrong. The favicons must have triggered something once, and must find what...

Comment: Did you add back deleted custom_theme_setup codes? Cause seems another function is still looking for that.

Comment: Yes, I am bringing it back and forth. Right now I have set it like it was. You can take a look at the site now if you'd like

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't delete a function that your theme is trying to use somewhere else. You can't solve your error in that way. So, put back your function

```
function custom_theme_setup() {
    add_theme_support( $feature, $arguments );
}
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'custom_theme_setup' );
```

since now you have another error caused by missing the above function.

Add your favicon links below the `<title>` tags. Somewhere below the

```
<!-- Normalize CSS --->
<link rel="https://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/3.0.2/normalize.css">
```

since those links are working correctly. And continue debugging, but better trying to find the exact problem.
Let's start by these questions:

1.Did you delete any other code from your functions.php? If it wasn't giving this error before, `$feature` and `$arguments` cannot be undefined before you changed something.

2.Did you change any other parts of the header.php related or not to favicons?

**Wait....**
Edit 1# - Checked your html code now... All that should be placed inside the `<head></head>` tags are in between body tags! Obviously that is a huuuge issue. Please link your latest header.php codes.

Edit 2# - A few stuff I noticed, noting here:

1. `<body> <! Avsluttes i footer.php -->`   - Browsers fix it anyways but you better fix the commenting yourself, `<!-- -->`
2. Did you enqueue your scripts on functions.php or elsewhere? All your scripts are giving 304 code on the console. Also, you can add your script tags to your footer.php before closing `</body>`. Ie. links like these below

`<script src="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory'); ?>/js/svgicons-config.js"></script>`
`<script src="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory'); ?>/js/svgicons.js"></script>`

Also you mentioned that you have copied functions etc from another theme or site...All these main errors saying `x is undefined` etc. might be caused by that. Probably you are (partially) missing related stuff.

Comment: Thanks. Yes. The favicons have worked for some minutes now, but the site is still misfunctioned... For some reason.

Comment: This line `add_theme_support( $feature, $arguments );` **will** give an error, since neither `$feature` nor `$arguments` is defined at that point. It's a leftover from something else @Olen (partly) removed. I think the main problem is actually the fact that Olen just switched on `debug_mode` for the first time - exposing a heap of "old" undiscovered and probably unrelated problems he never saw before... I'm withdrawing from this goose chase, as I don't see how it will benefit anyone except the OP, and that is not really what SO is about.

Comment: I actually believe `$feature and $arguments`, they possibly was there from another page I made. I based my site on that site to make it faster. I am feeling kinda bad and stupid right now... I believe you are right, I am now turning off the debug_mode to see if anything changes back to normal.

Comment: Okay, as I can see it all the scripts and so on are between the `<head></head>`. And then the `<body>` starts. Is that wrong?

Comment: @Mikk3lRo That's also possible, right. I'm just trying to suggest finding what's really wrong there instead of deleting anything that seems to be in use somewhere else.

Comment: @Olen Yes now the head part is okay. Let's see what else is wrong.

Comment: Seems the animation script is not working, as even after the page loads the opacity stays like: `.fadeInUpShort {opacity: 0;}`

Comment: Well seen. I temp. deleted them to see if it's possible to see other errors to clear this up.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/82832/discussion-between-olen-and-ekin).

Answer (score 1):

Err... did you look at line 42 of your `functions.php` ??

```
function custom_theme_setup() {
    add_theme_support( $feature, $arguments );
}
```

...should be rather obvious that `$feature` is undefined at this point. Comment out the line and the error will go away I suppose...?

Comment: Hehe, thanks. Deleted the one line, and the error got away. But site stilled misfunctioned. Deleted the whole function and site got a little bit better, but then got another error: `Warning: call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, function 'custom_theme_setup' not found or invalid function name in /customers/a/2/1/MYHOST/httpd.www/wp-includes/plugin.php on line 496`.  (Myhost because I don't want to be searched for, hehe).

Comment: You can't just delete a function to get rid of an error. It will definitely malfunction. As you see, that function was used in somewhere else. There is no way adding a favicon would crash your wordpress, unless you did something wrong somewhere.

Comment: Maybe I am totally wrong, but is it a possiblity that adding all the favicons triggered some errors? Because as I remember I have not done any big changes to any other files...

Comment: Do you not keep any sort of backup? Maybe something as simple as CTRL+Z in whatever editor you are using will solve your problem. (hold it down for a while)

Comment: Hehe, it's funny how much you do your backup, but nothing when something accours. I have reset the header.php till before the favicons. Working on other sites right now.

Comment: You should also delete the function call `add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'custom_theme_setup' );`.

Comment: I am sorry, I did not see your comment before now. Nothing changes after deleting those lines.